# Meteor Accounts new user verification link expiry

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor Accounts in my application to send welcome emails with verification link, I wonder if there is any way to configure the number of hours/ days after which the verification link expires?

Also I noticed that whenever I click on verification links, I get message that the verification link expired. I noticed this is also reported by many other developers so I was wondering if there were any fix for this issue?